# C# child class refuses to play ball - a little bit of polymorphic help please :-)

Tags: c#, interface, polymorphism, abstract-class

OK.. C# is not my forte and it's been a while since I got my head into this sort of thing and I have forgotten some things: I am struggling to get this too obey me :-) I am pretty sure what I want to do is possible within C# and I am pretty sure my abstracts and my interfaces are all to hell (I don't even know how to put the interface in but I know I need one)

ok here is the scenario

```
//abstract parent class
abstract class ActionType
{
    /***
     * this is a parent class not meant to ever be instaciated
     */
    public abstract void action();      
}

class ActionTypeSync : ActionType
{
    public override void action()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("doing sync");
    }
}

class ActionTypeRead : ActionType
{
    public override void action()
    {
         Debug.WriteLine("doing read");
    }
}
```

the following does not work

```
ActionType action = getActionType(1);
ActionType secondaction = getActionType(2);
```

**[ EDIT ]**

actually I was being too brief it's THIS bit that didn't work with error

Error   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ActionType' to 'ActionTypeSync'

```
processThings(action);
//debug out put "doing sync"    
processThings(secondaction);
//debug out put "doing sync"   

public ActionType getActionType(int i)
{
     if (i==1) return new ActionTypeSync();
     if (i==2) return new ActionTypeRead();
}

public void processThings(ActionTypeSync action)
{
     action.action();
}

public void processThings(ActionTypeRead action)
{
     action.action();  
}
```

**[/ EDIT ]**

How best do I need to restructure this.. please understand this is a an example for sake of brevity (as best as I could) I am summarising here - so some principles are better than some "why etc etc lectures" :-) thank you :-) I don't object to restructure in order to accommodate the polymorphic principle but I need this basic polymoprphic interface/class structure as is

Comment: this will fail at compiling, because i=1 is assignation, and you only can use equality i==1 to check, correct it!

Comment: What exactly do you mean with 'it doesnt work' ? Besides the compile error, it should work.  Conceptually, it is correct.

Comment: @Alberto,You've never seen a typo?  comment :-/ - editted typo

Comment: @ Frederik @JeffE I have edited to explain more fully

Comment: sigh.. .. downvote? sigh

Comment: apart from what Alberto wrote, you should adjust access modifiers. it doesn't compile since return type ActionType is less accessible than your method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Overlooking your syntactical errors, this is doing exactly what you told it to do.</strike>

It is calling the local `action()` on the specific type you instantiated, it doesn't do anything else because you haven't told it to (i.e. at no stage are you calling `base.action()`).

### Edit:

Based on your edit.... `ActionTypeSync` and `ActionTypeRead` can both be cast down to `ActionType`, but `ActionType` cannot be cast back up to either of those derived types. You can pass one of the derived objects around as an `ActionType` and the overridden `action()` method will be called, but you can't cast it implicitly or explicitly to the derived type. To fix this just change your method signatures:

```
public void processThings(ActionType action)
{
     action.action();
}
```

Because of this change you will now only need one method that will deal with both derived types because you have cast it down to its base type - IOW you can get rid of the `processThings(ActionTypeRead action)` method.

Comment: ok I have shown the error .. I thought it was "the bit I entered" but it was actually "the bit after" the actual code is rather long and not worth sharing all of it.. hence the breif

Comment: if by `syntactical errors` you simply mean the tiny (and, if I'm honest blatantly beneath mention) typo then ok, but otherwise if you meant something else can you elaborate?

Comment: thanks, but this is not what I need to do, there are about 12 children of the abstract parent class, and the situation is as it is.. simply put I need the complier to "trust" me at `processThings` when I tell it the method will be there - I believe interfaces do this?

Comment: @conners Interfaces tell the compiler that *"whatever implements me promises to have a method that looks exactly like this"* but the rest of the class' definition can be wildly different. The abstract base class says *"here is the method definition, you children need to supply the details"*. They are similar but subtly different. Quite often I will implement an interface on an abstract base class to achieve what I need. There is nothing wrong with your approach so far, you just had a small misunderstanding on how to achieve it.

Comment: yes, you are right, all along I had a issue, deeper down the program which was related to a Queue not liking how I did it, so I reverted the children to individuals to process their functions but it seems that was the blind alley -not this one here.. that error (the one I had had a few days back, which caused this cul-de-sac u-turn of the above was --it seems -- not faulty as after as it seemed)